# ArrayOfXXX class out of soap input param of array type

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, jax-ws, soap-client

I have a method with input param as Array. When I generate stub out of it creates List type.

But I want to know how to create a wrapper class around array type e.g. for class `Apple` it should create `ArrayOfApple`.

Is there any change needs to be done in class or any specific plugin need to be used?

Note: I am using `JAXWS` with `Apache CXF` implementation

Below is the sample code:

`EmployeeService.java`:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface="com.test.EmployeeService")
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.DOCUMENT)
public class EmployeeService {

    public String updateEmpRoles(@WebParam(name="EmpRoles")EmpRole[] empRoles) {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

`EmpRole.java` :

```
@XmlType(name="EmpRole")
public class EmpRole {
    private String empRole;

    public String getEmpRole() {
        return empRole;
    }

    public void setEmpRole(String empRole) {
        this.empRole = empRole;
    }
}
```

After publishing, wsdl is getting generated as below -

[image]

But what I expect is WSDL should create `ArrayOfEmpRole` and it should wrap `List<EmpRole>`.

Kindly help

In short - I want something that Björn doesn't want in below link. (In his case, it's automatically creating ArrayOfXXX, this is what I need) - [Arrays in SOAP method Parameters generated via JAX-WS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587645/arrays-in-soap-method-parameters-generated-via-jax-ws/46427736)

Comment: Probably get some more help if you put the code up that you're working with!

Comment: @JGlass I have added my code here. Inshort I want something that Björn doesn't want .(In his case its automatically creating ArrayOfXXX ,this is what I need) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587645/arrays-in-soap-method-parameters-generated-via-jax-ws/46427736

Answer (score 0):

I would switch from Code first to a Contract first approach which means start with the WSDL and generate a stub using wsdl2java from it. This way you can ensure that the WSDL looks like the way you want.

If you want to stick to the current approach, the easiest way to achieve a wrapper is probably to introduce another class.

Comment: Thanks Dennis for answering , but I have to stick to code first approach.Coming to the problem if I will introduce another wrapper class then it will have code changes in so many places (which I dont want).But if you see this link - people are generating ArrayOfxxx automatically which they dont want .Wondering how ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587645/arrays-in-soap-method-parameters-generated-via-jax-ws/46427736